# Query runs fine in SQL Server fails in oracle get ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I support an application that can either run on SQL Server or Oracle. A client asked for a query to export some data. I tested on my end in SQL Server and it ran fine.

They ran on their end and get this error:

> ORA-00923 FROM keyword not found where expected

I can't see anything wrong with the syntax.

Here's the query

```
select 
    c.ca1 wbs, c.ca2 ipt, c.wp, 
    t.cecode as resource, b.cost as cost_set, t.df_date as period, 
    sum(t.direct) as direct
from
    cawp c 
join 
    tphase t on c.program = t.program and c.cawpid = t.cawpid
join 
    costrepclass b on t.program = b.program and t.class = b.class
where 
    t.program = 'PO Orion Sum' 
    and t.cecode <> 'FTE' 
    and b.cost in ('acwp', 'bcwp', 'bcws', 'eac')
group by 
    c.ca1, c.ca2, c.wp, t.cecode, b.cost, t.df_date
```

Comment: You have to edit your select statement (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97385_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm)

Comment: if you put resource in double quotes, you'll be good e.g. select 1 as "resource" from dual;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RESOURCE is a keyword in oracle.  I don't think you can define it as an alias in your select statement.

Comment: Thanks, that did it.